# using lambda for code efficiency in iterating over dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, lambda

I am trying to eliminate excessive if statements for modifying values in a `Pandas dataframe`. I will eventually have one for each state, which is a lot of code and the if statement will be performed each time for every state. When my data source is in the list format, I successfully used `lambda` to make the code for efficient. This is demonstrated in the first code block. I am trying to replicate it with the data in the `dataframe` but am not sure how.

Efficient Code with Lists:

```
Projects = [['Project1', 'CT', 800], ['Project2', 'MA', 1000], ['Project3', 'CA', 20]]

for project in Projects:
    project[2] = {
        'CT': lambda: [project[2] * 1.4],
        'MA': lambda: [project[2] * 1.1],
        'CA': lambda: [project[2] * 1.5]
    }[project[1]]()

print Projects
```

Inefficient code with `dataframe`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data = [['Project1', 'CT', 800], ['Project2', 'MA', 1000], ['Project3', 'CA', 20]], columns=['Project ID', 'State', 'Cost'])

for project_index, project in df.iterrows():
    if project['State'] == 'CT':
        df.ix[project_index, 'Cost'] *= 1.4
    if project['State'] == 'MA':
        df.ix[project_index, 'Cost'] *= 1.1
    if project['State'] == 'CA':
        df.ix[project_index, 'Cost'] *= 1.5

print df
```

Comment: Instead pf those lambdas, why not just create a dictionary for the factor, `{'CT': 1.4, ...}`, and call like `project[2] *= factors[project[1]]`?

Comment: why not just do a many-to-one merge to create a column of constants `1.4 1.1 1.5` for each state `CT MA CA` and do the calculation column-wise. Iterating row-by-row is a bit slower.

Answer (score 2):

I'd construct a dict of your states and desired multiplication factor and just iterate over the dict to get the state and cost factor tuple, use `loc` and the boolean mask to selectively multiply only those rows in your df:

```
In [185]:
d = {'CT':1.4, 'MA':1.1, 'CA':1.5}
for item in d.items():
    df.loc[df['State'] == item[0], 'Cost'] *= item[1]
df

Out[185]:
  Project ID State  Cost
0   Project1    CT  1120
1   Project2    MA  1100
2   Project3    CA    30
```

Comment: Why would you loop through the `dictionary` and the not the `dataframe`? What if the dictionary has all 50 states, but the `dataframe` only has 4 projects. That seems inefficient and may even cause errrors.